# Difference between the formula for calculating flux across a simple open curve vs. across a simple closed curve?

Tags: calculus

I found this definition of flux in *Thomas's Calculus Early Transcendentals, 14th ed* on p.945:

> If $\mathit{C}$ is a smooth simple closed curve in the domain of a continuous vector field $\mathbf{F} = M(x, y)\mathbf{i} + N(x, y)\mathbf{j}$ in the plane, and if $\mathbf{n}$ is the outward- pointing unit normal vector on $\mathit{C}$, the flux of $\mathbf{F}$ across $\mathit{C}$ is
>
> Flux of $\mathbf{F}$ across $\mathit{C}$ = $\int_{C} \mathbf{F}⋅\mathbf{n}ds.$

Where flux is defined across a **simple closed** curve. However, I also found this [lecture](https://youtu.be/mEI7ACWmx_8?si=khQe7btVX-MHQQLx&t=87) where it is calculated across a simple but not closed curve (in part **c** of the exercise for example). The calculation in the video, as I observed, is done by using the same formula in the definition.

So what is the difference between the formula for calculating flux across a simple open curve vs. across a simple closed curve that the author of the book doesn't include the case for simple closed curves in the definition?

Comment: There is no difference in the formulas. When $C$ is closed you parametrize it with $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^2$ where  $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)\,.$ When it is not closed that last equality does not hold.

Comment: @KurtG. starting at 08:50, I still see that prof. Christine Breiner used the same equation for part (c) and evaluated the flux to be 0 despite the curve in that part is not closed?

Comment: I can imagine a lot of fluxes that are zero through non-closed curves. It may help if you develop some geometric intuition. Please refrain from asking us to watch videos. If there is an open math question transcribe what Prof. Breiner said and we will read that.

Comment: For example, if $\mathbf{F}$ is the tangent to $C$ what is its flux through $C\,?$ Hint: what is $\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\,?$

Comment: @KurtG. suppose the same formula as for closed curves applied, then it's $0$. But you mentioned in the first comment that: "When it is not closed that last equality does not hold.", so can I still apply the that formula?

Comment: Before we talk about "this" formula or "that" formula I highly recommend that you tell me how you calculate $\int_C\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\,ds$ when you parametrize it with $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^2\,.$ It would be even better if you chose a very concrete example.

Comment: Here's one example of the flux across a smooth *closed* unit circle that I quoted from the book: $\mathbf{r}(t) = cos(t)\mathbf{i} + sin(t)\mathbf{j}, 0 \le t \le 2\pi$ and $\mathbf{F}=(x-y)\mathbf{i} + x\mathbf{j}$. So the flux across the circle is: $\int_{C} \mathbf{F}⋅\mathbf{n} ds = \int_{0}^{2\pi} (cos(t)^2−sin(t)cos(t)+cos(t)sin(t)) dt=\pi$

Comment: Correct. How will this calculation change when you take half of the circle, say, the half that is above the $x$-axis? If you answer this convincingly to yourself I believe the entire question in OP is answered.

Comment: @KurtG. For half the circle, change the limits of integration to $a$ and $a + \pi$ ($0 \le a \le \pi$) that results in $\pi/2$ (if I'm not mistaken), **PROVIDED** the same formula (which the author restricted to smooth *closed* curves only) applies. So I still don't understand what the point of restricting to only closed curves?

Comment: Your calculations are correct. Let's not punish Thomas for the wording. I do not think he meant to restrict the definition only to closed curves. If still necessary you will find zillions of other resources about line integrals.

Comment: @KurtG., there's another source (also quite popular) that highlights the *closed* condition: https://web.uvic.ca/~tbazett/VectorCalculus/section-Flux.html. So I think that Thomas's book has a point in it.

Comment: It does [not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_scalar_field). What we want from a line integral is that if we break the closed curve into pieces the integrals must add up. $\pi/2+\pi/2=\pi$ in the example you did above. The closedness of the curve is absolutely not necessary. Believe me. Case closed.